# Beamer frame with text and two images

Tags: beamer, columns

I am trying to build a beamer frame where I have an itemize on the left and two images
on top of each other on the right. I just don't know how to put the second image on the right, so it won't be laying over the first image.
This is my code so far:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
\framesubtitle{subtitle}  
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item item1
        \item item2
    \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{5cm}
                 \includegraphics{image1}
    \end{column}
\end{columns} 
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding an empty line in between? And welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see my MWE and let me know, if you have tried that. You have to include an empty line between the two images.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\PassOptionsToPackage{demo}{graphicx}
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{title}
    \framesubtitle{subtitle}  
    \begin{columns}
        \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item item1
                \item item2
            \end{itemize}
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{5cm}
            \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{image1}

            \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{image2}
        \end{column}
    \end{columns} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh I didn't get that I can just put it in the same column. I tried to put it into an additional column. That works! Thank you so much!

Comment: @telina you are very welcome.